# Batch Typing Test Creation

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch script that displays a pangram- in this case, the well-known "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."-, times the user's speed, converts this speed to letters per minute (from letters per second), and also displays error (as in "2 missing letters" or "incorrect capitalization").

So far, I've been able to time the test based on a batch timer provided on this website:

```
@echo off
title 

pause
cls
echo The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
set starttime=%time%
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=:., " %%f in (`echo %starttime: =0%`) do set /a start100s=1%%f*360000+1%%g*6000+1%%h*100+1%%i-36610100
set /p typed=
set stoptime=%time%
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=:., " %%f in (`echo %stoptime: =0%`) do set /a stop100s=1%%f*360000+1%%g*6000+1%%h*100+1%%i-36610100
if %stop100s% LSS %start100s% set /a stop100s+=8640000
set /a elapsedtime=%stop100s%-%start100s%
set paddedtime=0%elapsedtime%
echo.
set speed=Typed in %elapsedtime:~0,-2%.%paddedtime:~-2% seconds
echo %speed%

pause
exit
```

Could somebody show me how to complete the rest of what I have to and give me an explanation on why whatever must be done is done that way?

My dilemma:

I've shown what I've already tried to finish, as seen in the giant blob of grey. I don't know how to properly compare the strings `%typed%` and `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.` using an `if` statement. Each time I try it, the batch-file simply exits after `%typed%` is set.

Also, I've tried to divide `3/5` by a variable containing `%elapsedtime:~0,2%.%paddedtime::~-2%` but the division does not work properly. I also cannot check for error because of trouble with comparisons using `if` statements here.

So this is the final product that I was able to put together with much help from Magoo:

```
@echo off
title 

C:
cd %windir%\System32
pause
for /l %%s in (5,-1,2) do (
cls
echo %%s seconds
ping localhost -n 2 >nul)
cls
echo 1 second
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
cls
set pangram=The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
echo %pangram%
set starttime=%time%
set /p typed= 
set stoptime=%time%
if not defined typed goto zero
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=:., " %%f in (`echo %starttime: =0%`) do set /a start100s=1%%f*360000+1%%g*6000+1%%h*100+1%%i
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=:., " %%f in (`echo %stoptime: =0%`) do set /a stop100s=1%%f*360000+1%%g*6000+1%%h*100+1%%i
if %stop100s% lss %start100s% set /a stop100s+=8640000
set /a elapsedtime=%stop100s%-%start100s%
set paddedtime=0%elapsedtime%
set total=%elapsedtime:~0,-2%.%paddedtime:~-2% seconds
if "%pangram%"=="%typed%" (set "accuracy=accurately") else (set "accuracy=inaccurately")
set /a nkeys=0
:keys
set /a nkeys+=1
set typed=%typed:~1%
if defined typed goto keys
set /a kps=%nkeys%0000 / %elapsedtime%
set /a kpm=(%nkeys%*600000) / %elapsedtime%
echo.
if %nkeys% neq 44 (echo %nkeys% key typed inaccurately in %total%
goto results) else (echo %nkeys% keys typed %accuracy% in %total%
goto results)
:zero
echo 0 keys typed inaccurately in %total%
echo.
echo 0 keys typed per second
echo 0 keys typed per minute
echo.
goto exit
:results
echo.
echo %kps:~0,-2%.%kps:~-2% keys typed per second
echo %kpm:~0,-2%.%kpm:~-2% keys typed per minute
echo.
goto exit
:exit

pause
exit
```

Can this code be further condensed?

Comment: I've shown what I've already tried to finish, as seen in the giant blob of grey. I don't know how to properly compare the strings %typed% and "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog." using an if-statement. Each time I try it, the batch-file simply exits after %typed% is set. Also, I've tried to divide 3/5 by a variable containing "%elapsedtime:~0,2%.%paddedtime::~-2%" but the division does not work properly. I also cannot check for error because of trouble with comparisons using if-statements.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add that information there? It's the part that's missing. If you do, the question you're asking will be much more clear. :-) Thanks.

Comment: Perfect. :-) I've cleaned up the formatting some for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
title 

pause
cls
set test=The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
echo %test%
set starttime=%time%
set /p typed=
set stoptime=%time%
IF NOT DEFINED typed ECHO Nothing typed?&GOTO :EOF 

for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=:., " %%f in (`echo %starttime: =0%`) do set /a start100s=1%%f*360000+1%%g*6000+1%%h*100+1%%i
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=:., " %%f in (`echo %stoptime: =0%`) do set /a stop100s=1%%f*360000+1%%g*6000+1%%h*100+1%%i
if %stop100s% LSS %start100s% set /a stop100s+=8640000
set /a elapsedtime=%stop100s%-%start100s%
set paddedtime=0%elapsedtime%
echo.
set speed=Typed in %elapsedtime:~0,-2%.%paddedtime:~-2% seconds
echo %speed%
if "%test%"=="%typed%" (echo 100%% accurate) else (echo there were errors)
set /a lps=440000 / %elapsedtime%
echo %lps:~0,-2%.%lps:~-2% letters per second
pause
exit
```

First item : Simply grab the start/stop time. Process it later, otherwise the processing time is included in elapsed.

Second: No need to subtract the correction factor since *stop-factor-(start-factor)* = *stop-start*.

Third: To compare strings potentially containing separators, `"quote the strings"` because the `IF` syntax is strictly `IF string1 operator string2 ...`
Further: If you are using `IF condition (thenaction) else (elseaction)` then the sequence <kbd>)</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>else<kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>(</kbd> must appear on the same physical line and `if` and <kbd>(</kbd> must also appear on the same physical line.

Fourth: Batch mathematics is strictly integer-only. Since you are dealing with hundredths of seconds, `4400` is 100*44 (44 is the length of your string).

---

```
cls
set test=The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
echo %test%
set starttime=%time%
set /p typed=
set stoptime=%time%
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=:., " %%f in (`echo %starttime: =0%`) do set /a start100s=1%%f*360000+1%%g*6000+1%%h*100+1%%i
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=:., " %%f in (`echo %stoptime: =0%`) do set /a stop100s=1%%f*360000+1%%g*6000+1%%h*100+1%%i
if %stop100s% LSS %start100s% set /a stop100s+=8640000
set /a elapsedtime=%stop100s%-%start100s%
set paddedtime=0%elapsedtime%
echo.
set speed=Typed in %elapsedtime:~0,-2%.%paddedtime:~-2% seconds
echo %speed%
if "%test%"=="%typed%" (echo 100%% accurate) else (echo there were errors)
SET /a nletters=0
:clloop
SET /a nletters+=1
SET typed=%typed:~1%
IF DEFINED typed GOTO clloop
ECHO %nletters% typed
set /a lps=%nletters%0000 / %elapsedtime%
echo %lps:~0,-2%.%lps:~-2% letters per second
set /a lpm=(%nletters%*600000) / %elapsedtime%
echo %lpm:~0,-2%.%lpm:~-2% letters per minute
```

Revised, enhanced and corrected - the display of lps was faulty.

Calculates length of string typed, so is auto-adjusting.

Note that because environment variables are always strings, tacking `0000` on the end is the same as multiplying by 10000.

note that if you sere to change the `set test` command to

```
set test=%*
```

then you could run this batch with a parameter

```
thisbatch a test string
```

and the test would be against "a test string"

---

Addendum to cater for no-entry-made: Added 'IF NOT DEFINED typed ..` line.

If no entry is made, `typed` will remain empty (actually, it will remain unchanged, so in general,

```
set var=defaultvalue
set /p var=
```

will set `var` to `defaultvalue` if no entry is made at the prompt)

Note the use of `if not defined` and `&` to cascade instructions on a line.

And to anticipate *how do you echo a <kbd>&</kbd>* - you "escape" it with a caret <kbd>^</kbd> thus: `^&`

---

Condensing OP's derived code:

```dos
@echo off
title 

C:
cd %windir%\System32
PAUSE
SET pangram=s
for /l %%s in (5,-1,1) do (
cls&IF %%s==1 SET "pangram="
CALL echo %%s second%%pangram%%
timeout /T 1 /NOBREAK>NUL)
cls
set pangram=The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
echo %pangram%
set starttime=%time%
set /p typed= 
set stoptime=%time%
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=:., " %%f in ("%starttime: =0%") do set /a start100s=1%%f*360000+1%%g*6000+1%%h*100+1%%i
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=:., " %%f in ("%stoptime: =0%") do set /a stop100s=1%%f*360000+1%%g*6000+1%%h*100+1%%i
if %stop100s% lss %start100s% set /a stop100s+=8640000
set /a elapsedtime=%stop100s%-%start100s%
set paddedtime=0%elapsedtime%
set total=%elapsedtime:~0,-2%.%paddedtime:~-2% seconds
if "%pangram%"=="%typed%" (set "pangram=") else (set "pangram=in")
SET /a nkeys=0
:keys
if not defined typed SET kpm=000&SET kps=000&GOTO results
set /a nkeys+=1&set typed=%typed:~1%&if defined typed goto keys
set /a kps=%nkeys%0000 / %elapsedtime%&set /a kpm=(%nkeys%*600000) / %elapsedtime%
:results
echo.
echo %nkeys% keys typed %pangram%accurately in %total%
echo %kps:~0,-2%.%kps:~-2% keys typed per second
echo %kpm:~0,-2%.%kpm:~-2% keys typed per minute
echo.

pause
EXIT
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed explanation! How would I go about displaying letters per minute?

Comment: The only problem I've found with this is that when no letters are typed, the script displays that 3 letters were typed when none were.

Comment: Rats! I had a lively debate with myself whether to make it more complex by checking for no-input and  simplify won...

Comment: Thanks once again Magoo! :)

Comment: Is it possible to further condense the final code that I posted?